# Make codes run for each individual

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, telebot

Is it possible to listen to each users contract events from the database at once? I've tried but it only works for one user.

Web3 python telebot

```
from web3 import Web3

import json,os,sys

import datetime

import requests

from db import *

import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("Telegram bot api will be here")



 
bsc = "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))

class BuyBot():

    def __init__(self,token,group):
        self.token = token
        self.group = group
        
    
    def main(self):
        print(f"EVENTS RUNNING FOR {self.token}")
        event_filter = web3.eth.filter({"address": web3.toChecksumAddress((self.token).upper()), "block_identifier": 'pending', })
        
        
        self.log_loop(event_filter, 2)
               
        
           
    def log_loop(self,event_filter, poll_interval):
        try:
            while True:
                for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
                    self.handle_event(event)
                    break
                time.sleep(poll_interval)
        except Exception as p:
            print(p)
            self.main()
            
    def handle_event(self,event):
        txn = json.loads(Web3.toJSON(event))
        hash = txn['transactionHash']
    
        if len(hash) > 0:
            transaction_recipt = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(hash)
            trs = web3.toHex(transaction_recipt['transactionHash'])
            usl_hash = f"https://bscscan.com/tx/{trs}"
            bot.send_message(self.group,url_hash)


def main():

    while True:
        print("am here")
        con = bot_db()
        mc= con.cursor()
        mc.execute('SELECT * FROM Contracts')
        rows = mc.fetchall()
        for all in rows:
            group = all[1]
            ca = all[0]
            
            check_ = BuyBot(ca,group)
            check_.main()

bot.polling(none_stop=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        print("Started")
        main()
    except Exception:
        print("rebooted")
        main()
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use concurrent.futures module with ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: Please do you have any examples